# Eliminating Epsilon Production for Left Recursion Elimination

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

Im following the algorithm for left recursion elimination from a grammar.It says remove the epsilon production if there is any

I have the following grammer

```
S-->Aa/b

A-->Ac/Sd/∈
```

I can see after removing the epsilon productions the grammer becomes

```
  1) S-->Aa/a/b

  2)A-->Ac/Sd/c/d
```

Im confused where the a/b comes in 1) and c/d comes in 2)
Can someone explain this?

Comment: The `|d` on the end of (2) is an error -- should be `A->Ac|c|Sd`

Comment: okay,i dont know it is what is written here may be its an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets look at the rule `S->Aa`, if `A->∈` then `S->∈a` giving just `S->a`, so together with the previous rules we get `S->Aa|a|b`

now lets check the rule `A->Ac` and `A->∈c` which gives us `A->c`.

what about `A->Sd`? I dont see how you got `A->d` as a rule. if that is a rule, then the string "da" is accepted by this grammar (`S->Aa & A->d --> "da"`), but try to construct this string with the original grammar - if you start with `S` and the string finishes with `a`, it means you must use `S->Aa`, but then in order to have a `"d"` you must use `A->Sd`, which forces us to have another `"a"` or `"b"`, meaning we cannot construct this string, and the rule `A->d` is not correct.